# How to select more than one variable from sql in join statement?

Tags: sql, sas

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table Final as
    select a.*, b.(more than one variable)
    from Table as a left join cool as b
    on a.xx = b.yy
    ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just list them:

```
select a.*, b.column1, b.column2, b.column3...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table Final as
    select a.*, b.variable1, b.variable2, [...], b.variableN
    from Table as a left join cool as b
    on a.xx = b.yy
    ;
quit;
```

You can get more information on SAS documentation.